# C socket recv returns number of bytes but nothing in the buffer

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

I have 2 programs a client and a server.  The client sends a 4 byte ascii command

```
client command: BD?\r
server reads:
```

server code

```
while(1) {

    int numbytes = 0;
    printf("MAIN: waiting for commands\n");
    memset(theRecvBuffer, '\0', THE_BUFFER_SIZE);
    numbytes = recv(theCSock, theRecvBuffer, THE_BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
    if(numbytes == 0) {
        printf("client socket closed\n");
        break;
    }
    if(numbytes == -1) {
        printf("cmd loop received socket error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        break;
    }
}
```

The server's recv call is returning 4 bytes but the buffer is filled with NULL bytes.
Is there anything that could cause the recv call to lose the buffer information?
Is there anyway I can debug what is going on in the recv call with print statements?
I am limited since this program is on a device with a different chipset so I can't use a debugger.
The errno does not help because there is no error since it returns 4 bytes.

Comment: How do you know recv() returns 4; the above code handles only returns <= 0. Please post the **real** code.

Comment: @wildplasser I took out a section of the code to show.  The real code is too long for a post.

Comment: Well, the error is in the other part, than.

Comment: At least show where you check the length of read buffer and retrieve its data.

Comment: your code doesn't show doing anything that would indicate the buffer is just nulls, other than the straightforward case where it obviously will be null after exiting this loop, so you must be leaving something out.

Comment: Do you alloc your buffer or only memset ?

Comment: The real code is threaded and long.  I was just wondering if someone ever ran into this problem.

Comment: Threaded, ah, ... do you share that buffer with other threads by any chance?

Comment: @Nikolai I thought that might be the problem.  Shared memory.  But I only use that buffer in the main thread.  I also only recv in one thread and send in the other.

Comment: Are you able to attach `gdb` to the process? Set a watchpoint on the first word of the buffer.

Comment: How is your socket initialised? do you use setsocketopt()?

Comment: @Nikolai I wish I could use gdb but the problem is happening on an embedded version of linux that is stripped down.  It does not happen on my test ubuntu system.

Comment: It definitely feels related to multi-threading and memory overrun somewhere. Try allocating that buffer from the heap on the same thread.

Comment: @Nikolai yea especially since it does not happen all the time only on certain requests.

Comment: And remove the memset(). It is useless, and can only do harm. Cargo cult programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a shared buffer in two different threads on two different sockets that I missed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using multiple threads, there is a possibility that another thread fails to read your buffer before your memset function zeros it in your main loop. This is just a guess but without the complete code it is hard to give a certain answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your code snippet is in fact literally taken from your code (which I doubt) then the problem is obvious: you clear the buffer before every call to recv.  Reading 4 bytes goes

```
clear buffer
recv() = 4
not 0 (eof)
not -1 (error)
loop
clear buffer
recv() = 0
is 0 (eof)
break
loop exits with cleared buffer
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strace -e trace=recv -s 65535 -v -p PID
```

should show you what the buffer looked like after the syscall before the user space gets to see it again.  The `-s` is the buffer size for strings to capture.  Optionally `-x` might be helpful if it's binary data.

Comment: yea unfortunately I am on an embedded device with a stripped down version of linux so there is no strace.

Comment: You should be able to compile and run the code on a development linux PC. Just replace the sytem dependent functions by stubs. That at least would enable you to get the skeletton code working.

Comment: @wildplasser yea thats the problem I am only seeing this on the embedded device and not on the development ubuntu system